# Extending header and footer along with the content

Tags: html, css

ISSUE

| <---- HEADER ----|............|

| <--------- Post content --------> |

| <---- FOOTER ----|............|

Here is the live example:

Version 1: http://myreadingmanga.info/wordpress/?p=1588 [Image is bigger than the window size]

Version 2: http://myreadingmanga.info/wordpress/?p=1603 [Image fits the window]

In version 1, the Header and footer leave out the space and do not cover the whole window.

I need it to be dynamic so that it expands according to the image size. I couldn't get much help in other topics. So if you can help, it would be good.

Comment: Please demonstrate your issue with a JSFiddle, and refrain from linking to external sites because they lose context, or suffer from link rot over time.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, it is here: http://jsfiddle.net/A_Manojkumar/hd2KV/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0):

Use a wrapper-DIV:

```
<div id="holder">
    <div id="header" style="width:100%"></div>
    <div id="content">
        <img src="...">
    </div>
    <div id="footer" style="width:100%"></div>
</div>`
```

Comment: Thanks Sebi, but can you be specific with the codes from here: http://jsfiddle.net/A_Manojkumar/hd2KV/embedded/result/

They have various parent and child divs.

Comment: I'm not going to write code for you. It's your code and I have given you an approach.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,I have inspect the whole css rules .Please remove the width:auto from the rule

```
body.single .content {
    padding: 0 20px;
    /*width: auto;*/
}
```

It works perfectly on my system
[image]

Comment: Asraful, Thanks for the reply. I want to retain the original image size since it is a magazine reading site. The admin wants to display the image as it is.

Any custom CSS rules for that? :)

Comment: OK I am trying it !Wait please

Comment: No problem. Take your time. Have been waiting for a solution for days. I tried position: fixed for header and footer but it comes along with the window.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, Asraful. I really appreciate it. But this was not the solution. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check it it works fine as your requirement!
Just add one extra property in the css entry rule

```
.entry {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #373737;
    border-top: 5px solid #F15123;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #141414;
    width: 1500px;/* add this property*/
}
```

Follow the step by step shown in the images
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please drag and drop every image in the new tab to see clear!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found out a solution. Just needed to add

```
body 
{ 
   position: absolute; 
   width: auto; 
}

.site-inner, .wrap 
{ 
   max-width: none; 
}
```